# ASP.NET pre-compile into a single assembly

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 web application which **needs to be pre-compiled into a single Assembly**. I have played around with the available options and I am getting following:

**1.** When I compile I get a separate assembly for each page as following:
[image: Multiple assemblies]

2. When I compile I get a single assembly of the web application but on the live server every page is dynamically compiled and a temp file is generated.

[image: Dynamic compiling]

3. I need a way to compile my web application into a single assembly which allows UI updates (HTML changes not the code) and does not generate temporary files.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to Create (or change) your project as (or to) an "Asp.Net Web Application" rather than the "Asp.Net Web Site".

This will cause your project to be compiled into a single dll, rather than the "dll per page" or "dll per directory" scheme that the web sites normally work off of.  It will also force you to resolve any type name problems (IE: if you have 6 pages called `Default`), It's important when you make a single assembly that fully qualified names be unique.

This will give you a proper project file (build script) and dump all your dll's out to the /bin folder when you compile.

You can then use something like [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) to combine all your assemblies in the /bin folder into a single dll if that's what you want to do.  This assumes all your references are managed assemblies, if you have any non .Net libs it's going to be a lot trickier, although still not impossible.

Comment: This is not what he is asking for. He would like to pre-compile his pages into a dll. Building a Web Application does not do that.

Comment: @Cipher: Apparently you missed the part in my answer where I say to use ILMerge to combine the assemblies?

Comment: No, I didn't miss anything. Your answer does not explain how to precompile the pages. Building a web app only compiles the base classes into the web project's dll. the actual code to render the pages gets compiled on first request and stored in the temporary dlls as seen in his question.

Comment: I suggest you try it out and post your results.  The web application currently loaded on my desktop right now suggests otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, I miss-read what he actually wanted. He doesn't want a pre-compiled app, but instead a web app from a single assembly. +1 for your answer in that case.

Comment: @Brook i didn't say your answer doesn't work. But your answer does NOT pre-compile the pages themselves.

Comment: @Brook, you are right. I still havent got an answer guys. When it was first developed in .Net-2.0 we had this problem,we updated to .Net-3.5 the developer spend days and managed to compile into a single DLL which did not generate temp files. Since migrating to .Net-4 this has started happening again and we can't find a solution.

Comment: @Cipher: Correct, it combines everything but the pages into a single dll, while leaving the pages so they are update-able, which is what the OP asked for.  I was unsure about what you were talking about exactly, I was thinking more along the lines of code-behind, controllers etc, which would be compiled into the web app.

Comment: @Usman Akram: If what you want is "no temp files" then you need to use the aspnet compiler as Cipher suggested, but you will lose the ability to update your .aspx's on the fly.

Comment: @Usman Akram: You could use the aspnet compiler, then use ILMerge to combine in your other references (elmah etc).  That would give you 1 assembly with absolutely everything, but you would not be able to update the aspx's on on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

The aspnet compiler is included with the framework. 
Here is a page describing how to use it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227972.aspx

Here are some additional pages for reference:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228015(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: That's not going to combine references (such as elmah.dll from OP) into the dll.

Comment: That's correct. It will not. Actually it wont solve his problem either. "I need a way to compile my web application into a single assembly which allows UI updates (HTML changes not the code) " in that case yes a web app is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot update the UI/html without the server recompiling the page using temporary files

All .aspx, .ascx files etc. are transformed to source code and then compiled. The only method ASP.NET provides to prevent that is to compile the pages and controls as well, but then your site is no longer updatable. In that case you would always need to redeploy the binaries for every update.

Any specific reason why you don't want ASP.NET to generate temporary files? It's a perfectly acceptable practice I think.

Comment: Our website has 5 types of pages i.e. TravelWebApp.Country is one type and TravelWebApp.City is another type. All the coutries pages inherit from TravelWebApp.Country (using Page directive properties). This allows us to create a new country page on the server any time without any re-compile. Because we have over 500,000 pages it generates a lot of temporary files and when server is restarted it takes ages to load the site.

Comment: @Usman You mean you generate an .aspx for each Country / City etc? Why not store the dynamic bits in a database and just reuse the same page? Or am I not understanding you correctly?

Comment: You are understanding it correctly. We are moving towards that solution but our website is huge and will take us time to get there. Needed this for the short term solution.

Comment: Are the files all in one folder? Did you apply basic ASP.NET performance tweaks (like setting debug="false" on the compilation element in web.config)?